# LINQ to SQL Implementation of Query Operator Error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have written what appears to be some pretty straightforward LINQ to SQL code:

```
Dim TestAcct = (
    From s In ITS_DB.SysValues
    Where s.vTable = STR_BQSync And s.Category = STR_TestAcct And s.Comment = STR_N).ToList
' other code
Dim _ChangedAccounts = (
    From  c In FinanceDB.Customers
    join t In TestAcct On t.Value Equals c.Customer_Account.ToString
    Select c).ToList
```

The problem is that at run time the second one throws an exception:

> Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query
>   operators except the Contains operator

I've seen some discussion about using contains but I'm not sure that applies in this case.  What is the local sequence referred to in the exception message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more testing and came up with an intriguing solution!

```
Dim TestAcct = (
    From s In ITS_DB.SysValues
    Where s.vTable = STR_BQSync And s.Category = STR_TestAcct And s.Comment = STR_N).ToList
' some other code
_ChangedAccounts = (
    From t In TestAcct
    join c In FinanceDB.Customers On t.Value Equals c.Customer_Account.ToString
    Select c).ToList
```

The first query is unchanged.  On the second one I simply reversed the order of the tables I was using.  It works fine!  I'm not sure why but it is ultra simple.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ToList` from the assignment to `TestAcct`. That will leave it as a query, and allow the second query to be resolved into a better final SQL query by Linq to SQL.

```
Dim TestAcct = (
    From s In ITS_DB.SysValues
    Where s.vTable = STR_BQSync And s.Category = STR_TestAcct 
                     And s.Comment = STR_N)
' other code
Dim _ChangedAccounts = (
    From  c In FinanceDB.Customers
    join t In TestAcct On t.Value Equals c.Customer_Account.ToString
    Select c).ToList
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to project just a collection of join keys from the first collection and then use `.Contains` on the matching key in the second query:

```
Dim TestAccts = (
    From s In ITS_DB.SysValues
    Where s.vTable = STR_BQSync And s.Category = STR_TestAcct And s.Comment = STR_N
    Select s.Value).ToList
```

And then

```
Dim _ChangedAccounts = (
    From  c In FinanceDB.Customers
    Where TestAccts.Contains(c.Customer_Account.ToString)
    Select c).ToList
```